# is there a way to create a QR code reader in web and that is also compatible when you open it on your mobile browser

Tags: javascript, php

i want to create a Qr code reader that is created on web, but i also want it to be compatible when it will be open on the browser of the mobile. i used instascan library it works fine on my computer but when it comes to my browser in mobile it doesn't seems to work or it is not compatible. can anyone help me please i really need it.

Comment: What do you mean it's not compatible?

Comment: This question is _way_ too unspecific and broad. We're here to help you sort out potential issues with your _existing_ code, but we're not here to do all the work for you.

Comment: i already have an existing code using the instascan js, it's working fine. but when i run it on my browser in my mobile. the camera seems to be frozen. sorry that i did not post some screenshots of my code, but is there any way to use instascan js in mobile broswer or is there other libraries that i can used?

Comment: @RenielMallari _i already have an existing code_ - As part of the SO Tour (which will have been recommended to you when posting this question), you're asked to include your existing code and any other supporting information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You most likely have [this](https://github.com/schmich/instascan/issues/150) or [this](https://github.com/schmich/instascan/issues/65) issue with instascan, are you possibly running android 7 or have a HTC device? Multiple people have reported issues with the instascan package with those devices. What you could try is [NIMIC QR scanner](https://github.com/nimiq/qr-scanner)

Comment: With link only answers, if those links die future users will be SOL. Try and include any relevant information/quotes within your answer - using the links as supplemental information.

Answer (score 0):

We used LazarSofts [jsqrcode](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode) before.

On desktop users could just upload photo with qr-code, and they had option to directly take photo with mobile phone.

I know this is not the cleanest solution, but it worked for us.

HTML:

```
<input type=file accept="image/*" capture=environment id="qr-scanner" tabindex=-1>
```

JS

```
// open the scanner
$(document).on('change', '#qr-scanner', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     var scanResult = scanQR(this);
});

// process the image with scanner
function scanQR(node) {

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
  qrcode.callback = function(res) {
    if(res instanceof Error) {
        handleScanResults(false);
    } else {
        handleScanResults(res);
    }
  };
  qrcode.decode(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(node.files[0]);
}

// handle scanner results
function handleScanResults(scanResult) {
  if (scanResult) {
      alert(scanResult);
  } else {
      alert('Scan error, try again.');
  }
}
```